# iPhone shows Connect to iTunes screen after turning off and back on

Tags: iphone, ios

I have iPhone4 and I shut it down by using power off button. Now I can't open the device unless I connect it to iTunes. I don't have backup and I don't want to lose my data and restore to factory setting when I connect to iTunes.

How should I proceed to bring it back up with all my actual data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TinyUmbrella](http://www.firmwareumbrella.com) to force your iPhone out of recovery mode:

Open TinyUmbrella, connect your device and click Exit Recovery.

---

For more information, see this forum post:

- http://www.whited00r.com/forum/index?topic=2835.0

Answer (score -1):

did you try to force reset the iPhone ?

[Force reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559)

Comment: It's too late for a force reset once it's demanding to be connected to iTunes.